# Searching a .json file for a item and displaying it's price using Discord.js

Tags: node.js, json, full-text-search, discord, discord.js

What I am trying to is:

User does !price (item)

The bot will search a json file,
eg.

```
[
    {
        "hi": 700000,
        "low": 650000,
        "name": "football"
    }

]
```

The bot will then reply with

```
Name: Football
High:650000
Low:70000
```

I cannot find any documentation online for searching a json file using discord.js.
If anyone could help would appriciate it!

Answer (score 0):

Finding an object in a JSON file isn't a Discord.js-specific thing. You can `require` a JSON file and then use [`find`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/find) to get the first item whose `name` matches the input.

```js
// the path has to be relative because it's not an npm module
const json = require('./path/to/json.json')
const item = json.find(object => object.name === 'football')
```

A full example:

```js
const {Client} = require('discord.js')
const json = require('./path/to/json.json')

const client = new Client()
const prefix = '!'

client.on('message', ({author, channel, content}) => {
  if (author.bot || !content.startsWith(prefix)) return

  const args = content.slice(prefix.length).split(' ')
  const command = args.shift()

  if (command === 'price') {
    // if the user sent just !price
    if (!args.length) return channel.send('You must specify an item!')

    const input = args.join(' ')
    const item = json.find(object => object.name === input)
    if (!item) return channel.send(`${input} isn't a valid item!`)

    // if you want to make the first letter of the name uppercased you can do
    // item.name[0].toUpperCase() + item.name.slice(1)
    channel.send(`Name: ${item.name}
High: ${item.hi}
Low: ${item.low}`)
  }
})

client.login('your token')
```